# Unity3d - setting gameobject position by percentage of view

Tags: unity, javascript

I am having trouble finding a way to set a gameobject's position with regards to the screen size. I am building a 2d game that I will be putting on iPhone, iPad, and Android. I need to be able to set the object's position to a percent of the view.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show what you've tried already. Giving us something to build off of, helps you get a better answer.

Comment: I am not sure where to start. I am checking out camera.WorldToViewportPoint. I think this might be what I need. I just need to figure out how to change it in viewport and give it back in world.

Comment: When you say you need to set the object's position, do you mean you need to set the position to something like 75% to the left of the screen, or do you mean something more advanced like scaling up/bringing forward so that it _fills_ a percentage of the screen?  The former is easy, just use http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html

Comment: Yeah, it ended up being viewportToWorldPoint. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You should post an answer detailing your method then. That way future readers can learn.

Answer (score 2):

The solution ended up being pretty simple. What I had to do is use the conversion of ViewportToWorldPoint.

```
Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3(.05, .90, 3));
```

The decimals are percentages of the screen. and the Z is distance from the camera.